# Django display html page based on user type

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to display the home page of my site based on the user type (admin, guest, student, etc.). It would be nice to display a link to the login page for guest users, but this link should be hidden for already authenticated users. For admins there should be a link to django-admin. Besides that there also some differences in the home page for other user roles.

What is a good way to implement this? I have several options for that:

1. Create html page for each user role: `home_guest.html`, `home_admin.html`, ...
2. Create a single html page but put some if-clauses inside it like `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

Comment: Definitely option 2. Parameter dependency is what templating is for.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with the documentation, using:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def email_check(user):
    return user.email.endswith('@example.com')

@user_passes_test(email_check)
def my_view(request):
        ...
```

which roughly means that if the user passes the test - provided on the email `endswith` here - then they will be able to see a view. In my case, I deviated a  bit from this and created a

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    status: 1,2 per se, in my model:
    student=1
    teacher=2
    STATUS_CHOICES = ((student, "student"),(teacher, "teacher"),)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES)
```

This lets you create an `is_status` property:

```py
    @property
    def is_status (self):
        return self.status
```

And then in your login view, you can play along with the properties. If it is 1, display this view, otherwise, display this other one.